# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android

may be it is the problem of minimum SDK but don't know how to solve it so kindly help me

```
[2014-10-26 00:54:30 - asa] C:\Users\Ahsan\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-26 00:54:30 - asa]
```

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow answering the same question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462128/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-android-studio)

Accepted answer from the question:

> Turns out that I had to make the target and compile version to L which
>   meant that I could not run my app on older SDKs. If you want your app
>   to run on SDK 19 and lower you have to set your compile and target
>   version to 19 and your min SDK to whatever version you need.
>
> Next you have to adjust your imports to the version that is compatible
>   with the SDKs that you have chosen to compile for. For example if you
>   want to use the v7 support library on sdk 19 you must import it like
>   this: compile compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'

So yes, it is an issue with minimum SDK, I would recommend that you raise your minimum SDK to one that supports this.

To raise or change your minimum SDK, change the following code in your  AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="x"/>`

Comment: Kindly Explain it with steps so that i can understand it

Comment: I have updated the original answer with steps on how to change your minimum sdk version additionally steps are located here as well. Step(s):  Change the following code in your AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="x"/>`