# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'

Tags: android, gradle, resources

Everything i try to sync Gradle this error comes up. I am using SDK 21 and I have all updates installed. I tried deleting the Value.xml, cleaning the Gradle, syncing it and trying to change the SDK version. and still it come up.

here is what goes wrong

```
C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.0\res\values-v11\values.xml
Error:(36, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(36, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(36, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(36, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
```

If you would like the project to see give me a message.
Im really new to android studio. Ive rebuild the app also.

Comment: Probably duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462128/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-android-studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure all your modules that have the support library as dependency also have the compile SDK set to 21. So go to Project Structure and check all the modules on the left hand side.

Comment: Is there a nice description how all relates with all the support stuff and Gradle and Studio. Really this is so messy! Seems like Android is a big hack. I think Studio should update this automatically, why should the developer need to manually change this to fit together?

Answer (score 0):

Updating compileSdkVersion & buildToolsVersion to latest available one worked for me.
These settings worked for me:

compileSdkVersion 26

buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'