# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I received these errors when i started new project in android studio.

> Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

File in android project contains error is given below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
  <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>
  <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored"/>
  <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Info.Media"/>
  <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Media"/>
  <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Time.Media"/>
  <style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Notification.Title.Media"/>
 </resources>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.anmol.checkboxapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

If anyone have solution of this problem so please help

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library. so do **one** of the following:

1.In your `Build.gradle` change

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

2.Or change:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

**As you are using** : `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`

i would recommend to use the 2nd method as it is using the latest sdk - so you can able to utilize the new functionality of the latest sdk.

**Latest Example** of build.gradle with build tools 27.0.2 -- [Source](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your_applicationID"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

If you face problem during updating the version like:

[image]

Go through this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495549/cannot-install-repository-and-sync-project-in-android-studio/43495905#43495905) for easy upgradation using [Google Maven Repository](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven)

**EDIT**

if you are using [Facebook Account Kit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android)

don't use: `compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'`

instead use a specific version like:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.12.0'
```

there is a problem with the latest version in account kit with sdk 23

**EDIT**

For [Facebook Android Sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)

in your `build.gradle` instead of:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk: 4.+'
```

use a specific version:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
```

there is a problem with the latest version in Facebook sdk with Android sdk version 23.

Comment: Thanks for pointing and giving the possible solutions but it works on     `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' ` @rafsanahmad007

Comment: where did you u made these changes

Comment: in your application --`build.gradle` file

Comment: If you are using Nativescript just add these lines to your app.gradle in App_Resources/Android

Comment: Bumping up buildtools and sdk version helped

Answer (score 7):

This problem was created by a regression in a recent release. You can find the pull request that fixes this problem at https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/339

Comment: Thanks - yes specifically; it was the 4.22.1 version in the link you provided that fixed the problem for me (I couldn't change my android compileSdkVersion for other reasons)

Comment: @Rod Nolan seriously I want to buy you a beer or donut or something, the sanity and hair I've been spared from losing over this by your comment is worth MONEY to me.

Comment: I swear, of all the singular sources of problems I've had in the last 5 years, "Facebook SDK" is the top of the list.  Across iOS and Android, and different projects, ones I've created and ones I've adopted from others, nothing else comes close.  So there's a problem in one version (as with many) of the Facebook SDK for Android, and has been solved by a hard-coded version number.  This is the solution.

Answer (score 6):

I found it, I was trying to compile my app which is using facebook sdk. I was made that like augst 2016. When I try to open it today i got same error. I had that line in my gradle " compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+' " and I went https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x this page and i found the sdk version while i was running this app succesfully and it was 4.14.1 then I changed that line to " compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1' " and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

in my case i was using `compile sdk 23` and `build tools 25.0.0` just changed `compile sdk` to 25 and done..

Answer (score 2):

The ideal answer found in the forum mentioned above is this:

```
sed -i 's/facebook-android-sdk:4.+/facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1/g' ./node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle
```

This works

Comment: The problem in editing `node modules` is every clean install, or working on new device or while running on CI you have to edit the node modules file. This cannot be the standard way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me (**Android Studio**) :

1) Use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S</kbd> or **File -> Project Structure**

2) and increase the level of SDK "**Compile SDK Version**".