# Error retrieving parent for item in android studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-styles

> These are some errors which I'm facing and answers posted here are not
>   helping me either. Perhaps anyone could suggest something else:

```
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

> This is my gradle file and I can't see why it is not accepting the
>   updated gradle built:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.allianz.azemployee"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.github.szugyi:Android-CircleMenu:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.bcgdv.asia.lib:fanmenu:1.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have been trying some options from stackoverflow but none seems to work. The `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'` is underlined in red `This support library should not use a different version(25) than the compile version (23)` 
What does this mean? Also What is that error in XML?

> Update
>   I'm stuck with this error now:

```
Error:(24, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@color/common_action_bar_splitter').
/Users/AmosPune/Desktop/AZEmployee_2_sept_final/AZEmployee_2_sept_final/app/src/main/res/layout/tab_layout.xml
/Users/AmosPune/Desktop/AZEmployee_2_sept_final/AZEmployee_2_sept_final/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/layout/tab_layout.xml
Error:(24, 25) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@color/common_action_bar_splitter').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: change your compileSdkVersion  version to 25

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2'

Comment: Detail answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144415/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name

Answer (score 6):

**Step 1**

At first call **compileSdkVersion 25** .

```
compileSdkVersion 25 
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
```

**Step 2**

You should use **v7:25.2.0/v7:25.3.1** version instead of **v7:23.4.0** .

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0' //or 25.3.1
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Restart** and **Run** .

Comment: Thanks I did that but stuck with another error which I'll post as an update in the question.

Comment: Current version is 25.3.1. [See this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v7-appcompat)

Comment: @AlbAtNf indeed .

Comment: I have added the new error if you could please look at it once.

Comment: @KaranThakkar okay . show line where using `common_action_bar_splitter`