# Android aapt.exe resources expection

Tags: android, android-resources, aapt

This is not a duplicate question. I have already tried all solutions related to this problem. But none of them are worked.

I have imported project to my system and got error.

[image]

To overcome with this error i have installed all build tools versions.

This is my build.gradle file.

[image]

My target sdk version and compile sdk version and build tool version are same.

I have downgraded the build tool version with specific target and compile sdk versions. But none of them are working for me.

I have also checked that *Does it contain any Capital alphabet* in values  , drawable and other files. But all seems ok.

**ERROR :**

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Advanced help would be appreciated !

Comment: Can you give a you're logcat output?

Comment: This is the only error while trying to run the application

Comment: I faced this kind of problem. If there is no logcat output the u can see this can probably help you

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144415/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name]

Comment: and please let me know if it works or not. or if you solved by own.

Comment: @TanvirDurlove I have updated question with Error

Comment: Can you try a little change of you're buildToolsVersion?  Some build vesion contains bug try it with 21.0.1

Comment: Then i must change target and sdk version too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154436/discussion-between-tanvir-durlove-and-piyush-gupta).