# Error:(785) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium'

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I solve it? Please help me 
When I rebuild my project then it gives me following error

> "Error:(785) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium' ".
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>

<style name="Default" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fast_scroll</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/fast_scroll_preview</item>
</style>
<style name="NoTitle" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fast_scroll</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/fast_scroll_preview</item>
</style>
<style name="FullScreen" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fast_scroll</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/fast_scroll_preview</item>
</style>

<style name="font1" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorA</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font2" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorA</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font3" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorA</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font4" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorB</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font5" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorC</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font6" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorC</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font7" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorC</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font8" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorC</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font9" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorC</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font10" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorD</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font11" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorD</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font12" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorE</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font13" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorE</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font14" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorH</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font15" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorH</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font16" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorH</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font17" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorH</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font18" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorH</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font19" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorD</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font20" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorI</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font21" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorH</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font22" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorH</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
</style>

<style name="font23" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorD</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
```

```
This is my gradle file

    // Project information
    buildDir = 'bin'

    def getPackageName() {
  return "com.neveroam"
}

def firebaseEnable() {
  File googleFile = new File('google-services.json')
  return googleFile.exists()
}

buildscript {
  File googleFile = new File('google-services.json')
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    if (googleFile.exists()) {
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
  }
  androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.3'
  androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.14'
  if (firebaseEnable()) {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
  } else {
    compile fileTree(include: 'gcm.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
  }
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
}

if (firebaseEnable()) {
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

//// Submodule Dir /////
def submoduleDir = ['submodules/mediastreamer2/java/src',
                    'submodules/linphone/java/j2se',
                    'submodules/linphone/java/common',
                    'submodules/linphone/java/impl',
                    'submodules/linphone/coreapi/help/examples/java']
////////////////////////

///// Exclude Files /////
def excludeFiles = []
// Exclude firebase file if not enable
if (!firebaseEnable()) {
  excludeFiles.add('**/Firebase*')
  println '[Push Notification] Firebase disabled'
} else {
  excludeFiles.add('**/gcm*')
  println '[Push Notification] Firebase enabled'
}
excludeFiles.add('**/mediastream/MediastreamerActivity.java')

def excludePackage = []

excludePackage.add('**/gdb.*')
excludePackage.add('**/libopenh264**')
excludePackage.add('**/**tester**')
excludePackage.add('**/LICENSE.txt')
/////////////////////////

android {
  defaultConfig {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    applicationId getPackageName()
    multiDexEnabled true

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
    disable 'MissingTranslation', 'UnusedResources'
  }
  // Signing
  signingConfigs {
    release {
      storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
      storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
      keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
      keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      def srcDirs = submoduleDir
      srcDirs.addAll(['src/android'])
      java.srcDirs = srcDirs
      resources.srcDirs = srcDirs
      aidl.srcDirs = srcDirs
      renderscript.srcDirs = srcDirs
      res.srcDirs = ['res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
      jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
      java.excludes = excludeFiles

      // Exclude some useless files
      packagingOptions {
        excludes = excludePackage
      }
    }

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
  }
  sourceSets {
    androidTest {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      def srcDirs = submoduleDir
      srcDirs.addAll(['src/android',
                      'src/androidTest'])
      java.srcDirs = srcDirs
      resources.srcDirs = srcDirs
      aidl.srcDirs = srcDirs
      renderscript.srcDirs = srcDirs
      res.srcDirs = ['res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
      jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
      java.excludes = excludeFiles

      // Exclude some useless files
      packagingOptions {
        excludes = excludePackage
      }
    }

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
  }
}

// Grant permissions
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  def applicationId = getPackageName()
  def adb = android.getAdbExe().toString()
  def variantName = variant.name.capitalize()
  def grantPermissionTask = tasks.create("grant${variantName}Permissions").doLast({
    "${adb} devices".execute().text.eachLine {
      "${adb} shell pm grant ${applicationId} android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO".execute()
      "${adb} shell pm grant ${applicationId} android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".execute()
      "${adb} shell pm grant ${applicationId} android.permission.CAMERA".execute()
      "${adb} shell pm grant ${applicationId} android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE".execute()
      "${adb} shell pm grant ${applicationId} android.permission.READ_CONTACTS".execute()
      "${adb} shell pm grant ${applicationId} android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS".execute()
    }
  })
}

task runApplication() {
  def result = exec {
    executable = android.getAdbExe().toString()
    ignoreExitValue true
    args = ['shell', 'monkey', '-p', getPackageName(), '-c', 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER', '1']
  }
}
```

Comment: post your styles.xml and build.gradle files

Comment: post you build.gradle file. I thinks its due to sdk. Take reference of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144415/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name